# What's the better preposition to use with "love" -- "love for" or "love of"?

Tags: prepositions

> He had always had a fond love ***of***  literature.

*Love of* something or *love for* something? What's the correct preposition to be used with *love*, in the above context?

Comment: *Love of* permits a reversal of direction, *love for*, definitely not.

Comment: An *unfond* love of literature??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not an either-or situation. You can use either preposition.

> Love of money is the root of all evil.
>
> *The Love for Three Oranges* (opera by S. Prokofiev)
>
> I have nothing but love for my children.
>
> "For the love of God, why would you say such a thing!"

Note: "of" may be used to express that the object of the preposition is the thing that loves, as in the last example above. You could say something like "I would do anything for the love of a good woman," meaning that you want to get her love (as well as, presumably, to give it).

Comment: In _I have nothing but love for my children_, _for_ is the complement (is that the word?) of _have_, not of _love_, so that case is not like the others. Using _of_ in that sentence instead would change the meaning from "what have for my children is nothing but love" to "I don't have any money or, well, anything else, except that I have love of my children".

Answer (score 2):

I think, "love of" is ambiguous. Consider this. "The love of his wife was undiminished."
Who has love for whom? "The love for his wife was undiminished."
It is clear that either the speaker or someone else loved his wife.

Answer (score 0):

love for-  in support of or in favor of
example: His love for his family inspired him to work his hardest every day.
love of- almost the same in meaning with "fondness for":having an affection or liking for
example: His love of cats put him on national TV.